# Как сделать кнопку удаления товара из корзины, при этом поместитть ее не на странице корзины woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

[image: Попап корщины]

На сайте имеется попап, что отображает товары в козине. Но кнопки удаления товара из корзины не работают. Имеется ли возможность реализовать данную функцию?

```
foreach($items as $item => $values) { $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id());$price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
```

Использую данный цикл для отображения товаров в попапе

Answer (score 0):

Отправлять AJAX-запрос c ID товара по нажатию на кнопку, на беке

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cartProductId => $cartProduct ) {
  if ( $cartProduct['product_id'] == нужный ID ) {
    WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cartProductId );
  }
}
```

P.S. в функцию обработки не забыть добавить `global $woocommerce;`